# MySQL error 1064 - what is causing it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two similar queries, and the second one is throwing a 1064 error and I can't figure out why. Do you see the issue?

```
select * from node 
join field_data_field_taxonomytopics as tt
on node.nid = tt.entity_id
where tt.bundle = 'magazine_article' and tt.entity_id = 61928;

SELECT 
FROM 
node node
INNER JOIN field_data_field_taxonomytopics field_data_field_taxonomytopics ON node.nid = field_data_field_taxonomytopics.entity_id
WHERE  (field_data_field_taxonomytopics.bundle = 'magazine_article') AND (field_data_field_taxonomytopics.entity_id = '61928')
```

Comment: You are not selecting anything.

Comment: ah! you're right! Thanks, I kept looking at it and never saw it. This is the answer.

Comment: the inner join in the second query will probably throw an error right after you fix the selecting nothing error. Also, why are you sometimes using twice the same name `SELECT FROM node node INNER JOIN...` ?

Comment: I wish that the MySQL error messages would be more descriptive, the 1064 error can mean almost anything

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR Error #1064 means that MySQL can't understand your command. To fix it:
>
> Read the error message. It tells you exactly where in your command
>   MySQL got confused. Check the manual. By comparing against what MySQL
>   expected at that point, the problem is often obvious. Check for
>   reserved words. If the error occurred on an object identifier, check
>   that it isn't a reserved word (and, if it is, ensure that it's
>   properly quoted).

I am guessing the issue here is that in the FROM clause you wrote the table name twice "node node", in addition, you are not selecting anything.

SELECT *****
FROM 
node <strike>node</strike>

I hope that will fix the error.

Comment: The issue is in `SELECT FROM`. There's nothing selected. `SELECT FROM node node` is not an issue, it's merely an alias for table `node`. The silly part is that alias is the same as table name :)

Comment: That is a little silly, but that's how Drupal Views outputs the query.